# Issue with alignment in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I've been working on a site, and I'm having a problem with CSS in Firefox. In Chrome, the site looks fine:

[image: Chrome]

However, in Firefox the alignment is awful:

[image: Firefox]

Could anyone give a suggestion on what I should look for when starting to resolve this issue? The site is http://preview.ovalbit.com/textlocker. It appears to be an issue with Bootstrap alignment in Firefox, as the labels are appearing on to the left, rather than on top of the inputs.

Comment: When I look at it in Firefox (31.0), it looks fine.

Comment: Yes, all good on Firefox 30 as well. Tested on both Linux Ubuntu and iOS X. Which version are you testing it on?

Comment: How are you testing it to get it to look like that?